# Spotting and Pointing - Notice checks

Tags: d20-system, mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

This covers at least the Mutants and Masterminds system. I would prefer an answer for 2E, but anything extensible to 3E would be handy too. If there's a generic d20 rule that applies, that would probably work as well, since the Mutants and Masterminds system is descended from that base system.

Basically, I recently had a situation where one character was using Hide in Plain Sight and rolled a good Stealth check. Another character had Magic Awareness as a sense, and rolled a high enough Notice check to spot the hidden character by the magic they were radiating. They spotted the hidden character, and tried to point them out to another character. It seems like being able to point out where a hidden person is would give some bonus to spotting them, but I'm not sure how much. Is there any rule that covers this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is not a specific rule which covers this.

Thus, it would be best to fall back on Rule 0: The GM is right.

I would rule it as such: All characters able to see and hear the character who spotted the HIPS-hidden character would be entitled to a new Notice check with a +2 bonus.

In the event that the character who Noticed the hidden character had some form of sense-sharing (Mental Link, etc) and was using it, it could be an automatic success.

If the spotter had a better way to indicate where the hider was (such as an Illusion power that could outline him in a mystical glow, or Light Control that could draw a glowing green neon arrow pointed at him) that bonus could be increased, possibly capped by the Rank of the power used.

Just remember that NPCs with powers can often do the same thing, though it may be worth a Hero Point for the hiding character if that happens.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.